# How to apply a greater/less than DateTime query in Sitecore using the `IQueryable<ContentSearchResult>` Linq?

Tags: solr, content-search, graphql

How do you apply a `DateTime` field comparison in Sitecore using the `Sitecore.ContentSearch` SDK?

The `ContentSearchResult[string key]` function always returns a string which cannot be cast into a `DateTime` for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use the following function overload:

`ContentSearchResult[ObjectIndexerKey key]`.

Example Query:

```
queryable = queryable.Where(p =>
   ((DateTime)p[(ObjectIndexerKey)"Date"]) > lastWeek.Boost(4f)
);
```

*Note*: The boost above does not appear to be translated in the query